# Shortcodes inside a shortcode - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a shortcode which display the employees, the HTML look somthing like that:

```
<ul class="employees">

<li><img src=""> <h5>name</h5> <p>description</p></li>
<li><img src=""> <h5>name</h5> <p>description</p></li>
..

</ul>
```

So I created 2 shortcodes:

[start_employee] - which contains `<ul class="employee"> .. </ul>`

[employee] - which contains content about the employee

And it should work like that:

```
[start_employee]
[employee img=".." name=".." description=".."] 
[employee img=".." name=".." description=".."] 
[/start_employee]
```

but when I put it in the wordpress editor the html look like that:

```
<ul class="employee">
[employee img=".." name=".." description=".."] 
[employee img=".." name=".." description=".."]
</ul>
```

I think I know why.. because the fuunction of start_employee contain:

```
return '<ul class="employee">'.$content.'</ul>';
```

What should I do that it read it as a shortcode?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you perhaps post the complete code of the shortcode's function? It would be easier to help you and it could help better other people looking for similar solutions.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Shortcodes do not automatically nest -- you have to call `do_shortcode($content)` yourself. See the `caption_shortcode()` example on http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API.

Answer (score 21):

You have to use shortcodes recursively to get the result.

```
function start_employee($attr,$content){
          return '<ul class="employee">'.do_shortcode($content).'</ul>';
}
add_shortcode("start_employee","start_employee");

function employee($attr,$content){
          return '<li><img src=""> <h5>name</h5>; <p>description</p></li>';
}
add_shortcode("employee","employee");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have a recursive function set up, as in Cart66, you can do something like this:

```
echo do_shortcode('[hide_from level="membership" ]<strong>You may only order this item if you are a member. Become a <a href="http://yoursite.com/beta/member-log-in/">member</a>.</strong>[/hide_from]');
echo do_shortcode('[show_to level="membership"]'.do_shortcode('[add_to_cart item="'.$prefix.get_post_meta($post->ID,'_et_cart66_product_id',true).'" ]').'[/show_to]');
```