# wordpress nested shortcode - how to enforce order of shortcode processing

Tags: wordpress

i am just trying to write my own plugings on wordpress

i wrote this to download code from a github raw file

post:

```
[github raw="https://raw.github.com/pmontu/PatientRecordsWindows/402fcb1706f408428aa1a6df2a82fbbba1fc4071/PatientRecordsWPF2/Domain/Media.cs"]
```

plugin:

```
function github_func( $atts ) {
    extract($atts);
    return file_get_contents($raw);
}
add_shortcode( 'github', 'github_func' );
```

it works but code with tags are not displayed properly

[image]

so i am trying to apply the syntax highlighter plugin to the downloaded code

with syntax highlighter:

```
[c language="#"][github file="https://raw.github.com/pmontu/PatientRecordsWindows/402fcb1706f408428aa1a6df2a82fbbba1fc4071/PatientRecordsWPF2/Domain/Media.cs"][/c]
```

but looks like the precedence is messed up
[image: url has not been fetched before highlighting]

i read nested shortcodes do work if do_shortcode() is called, how exactly do i implement it?

Comment: related discussion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773186/shortcodes-inside-a-shortcode-wordpress

Comment: +1 to related discussion; @Montu: have you looked at the existing [plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=gist) for embedding Gists? I like [Simple Gist Embed](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-gist-embed/).

Comment: Also see: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/84479/24260

Comment: thank you, i hope the plugin is safe! i have used a bad one before!! interested link, i ll look into it..