# Shortcode inside a shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

As my question, very simple:

`[buddyxxxx room=[URLParam param='room']-oki password=[URLParam param='password'] default_language=fr show_watermark=false width=100%]`

My shortcode works until `[buddyxxxx room=[URLParam param='room']`, then it ends without taking count of my other parameters.

`[URLParam param='room'] - [URLParam param='password']` are from a URL query.

Any idea how to format this to get the full shortcode?

Update : 
snippet : It just prints the shortcut,

```
<?php
echo '[buddymeet room=' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["room"]) . ' password=' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["password"]) . ']';
?>
```

With echo do shortcode, nothing appear

a function :

```
add_shortcode('room', 'get_name');

function get_name() {

   echo do_shortcode ('[buddymeet room='.$_GET['room'].' password='.$_GET['password'].']');

}
```

And Nothing appear on screen,

This method :

```
[buddyxxxx room=[URLParam param='room']-oki password=[URLParam param='password'] default_language=fr show_watermark=false width=100%]
```

only half work

Comment: Why are you passing the URL params to the shortcode? Why not just grab the URL params in the `buddyxxxx` shortcode function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shortcodes inside a shortcode - wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773186/shortcodes-inside-a-shortcode-wordpress)

Comment: i tried many ways, even with gravity form, wpforms, contact 7 to get a shortcut, at the moment i try a workaround with 

<?php
echo '[buddyxxxx room=' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["room"]) . ']';
?> with xyz-snippet shortcut.
It just print the shortcut, 
i tried 

<?php
echo do_shortcode('[buddyxxxx room=' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["room"]) . ']');
?>

and nothing appear on screen

Comment: You need to post your actual shortcode code. We have no idea if your shortcode function is even setup correctly.

Comment: snippet : It just prints the shortcut, 

<?php
echo '[buddymeet room=' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["room"]) . ' password=' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["password"]) . ']';
?>

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but do you have the password in your URL? That is a really bad idea. Now your question, your first one won't work because you don't have `do_shortcode` around that. I still think you are going about this the wrong way. The shortcode should just be a shortcode and then use the function to get the `$_GET` values.

Comment: so i try an other way, maybe a js script is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for update :

This was because wp doenst allow shortcode nested code.