# How do I add sharelinkes shortcode in short code

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I need to to add a short code into a short code in WordPress.

```
[mycred_link href="http://www.mycred.me"]View portfolio[/mycred_link]
```

This short code above is a short code from *myCred plugin*, it gives users points when they click on the link inside the short code.

What I need is:

To show a *Facebook* share link, inside the short code using. I already have a short code that generates a Facebook share link.

I need something like this:

```
[mycred_link href="[facebook_share_link]"]View portfolio[/mycred_link]
```

To give users points when they share my posts on Facebook. I tried it but it didn't work.

I also tried this code below, it Gives point to users and opens facebook.
But facebook says that URL is invalid.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( "[mycred_link href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>']View portfolio[/mycred_link]"); ?>
```

If I put double quote after the href the wordpress footer will disappear completely, am running the second code on my footer.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside the code of myCred plugin. As you can see from the source code of the plugin wp-content/plugins/mycred/includes/shortcodes/mycred_link.php what you pass inside the href attribute doesn't get parsed with do_shortcode therefore you will not be able to insert.

As you can see from this answer:[Shortcodes inside a shortcode - wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773186/shortcodes-inside-a-shortcode-wordpress) wordpress shortcodes doesn't stack automatically.

Luckily for you the function end with:

```
return apply_filters( 'mycred_link', '<a ' . implode( ' ', $attr ) . '>' . do_shortcode( $link_title ) . '</a>', $atts, $link_title );
```

So w/o touching the plugin source code you can use the filter and then do something with the href. My guess is something like this (not tested)

Inside your function.php in your theme folder insert something like this:

```
add_filter('mycred_link','edit_mycred_link',10,3 );
function edit_mycred_link($link_html, $atts, $link_title){
    return str_replace('__edit_mycred_link__',do_shortcode('[facebook_share_link]'),$link_html);
}
```

And then inside your template file / post content

```
[mycred_link href="__edit_mycred_link__"]View portfolio[/mycred_link]
```

That should work

Comment: I have a very little knowledge about php, The code returned a fatal error on the website, so I have to remove it through the cpanel.

Comment: Hello bro Any help on this, I really need this code.

Comment: Wordpress says "there has been a critical error on your website"

Comment: Please temporary enable wp_debug and see what's going on. You should see the real error

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. I asked the question on wordpress forum and a moderator gave it to me.

```
    <?php
echo do_shortcode( '[mycred_link href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' . urlencode( get_permalink()) . '"]View portfolio[/mycred_link]');
?>
```